# trying to query local datastore and place results into NSArray

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.3

I am trying to fetch objects from parse local data store (yes i have enabled parse local datastore). In my parse Books class, i have a column with "user" pointer to User class.

```
var bookObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
```

The below method is placed after viewdidload.

```
 func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore(){
        var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Books")
        query.fromLocalDatastore()
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if(error == nil){
                var temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray
                self.bookObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                println(error)
            }


        }
    }
```

I'm having an error message at

```
var temp: NSArray = objects as NSArray
```

it says:

```
[AnyObject]? is not convertible to NSArray
```

The line after it where i cast it as NSMutableArray, i have to use `!` due to the temp variable error.

so what am i missing out here?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific other reason, you should declare your `temp` array to use the native swift `Array` type rather than `NSArray`, like so

```
var temp: [AnyObject] = objects!
```

This should work right off the bat, as objects is of type `[AnyObject]?`.